# Scala: Getting the percentage of the number of objets in a list

Tags: scala, function, percentage

Considering the following dataset called "df":

```
Name | Sex
John | man
Peter| man
Henry| man
Mary | woman
```

I would like to define a function that returns me this:

```
Percentage of men: 75%
Percentage of women: 25%
```

I'm having trouble because "men" and "women" are string type and to add the percentage symbol (%). Also I would like to clarify that I'm using IntelliJ to code in Scala.

Comment: Look at `groupBy()`. If you `groupBy(_.Sex)` then you'll have all the `man` elements in one `List` and all the `woman` elements in another.

Comment: Just to clarify: is it pure Scala or is it a Spark dataset?

Comment: It is Scala! I'm using IntelliJ

Comment: The question is how is this stored. Is this a `List` of some case class? Is it a Spark dataset? Is it literally in a file as plaintext and needs to be parsed?

Comment: It's stored as a "Seq" . The dataset comes from a csv after being parsed. For example, I would start the function like: def function (x: Seq[df]): (Double, Double) =

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by jwvh, you can do something like this:

```scala
case class Person(name: String, sex: String)

val df: Seq[Person] = ???

df
  .groupBy(_.sex)
  .map { case (sex, persons) =>
    val percentage = persons.length * 100 / df.length
    s"Percentage of $sex: $percentage%"
  }
```

This will give you a `Seq[String]` which you can use how you'd like.